# How to get list from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

List information:

SharePointApplication = http://xxx/sites/Development%20Kit/CHC/_vti_bin

RootFolder = /sites/Development Kit/CHC/Lists/Code Sync Tracking/D/L1

---

i want get picture-3 L1 data:

Title/Sync Status ..etc

how to do it?

[image]
[image][image]

my sample code

```
SP.ClientContext clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(url);
SP.List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Code Sync Tracking");
clientContext.Load(list);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

SP.CamlQuery camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'><Query></Query></View>";
camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/Code Sync Tracking/D/L1/";
SP.ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);            
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); <=exception happen
```

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

How do i modify the code correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Go to List Settings > Export To Excel

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about SharePoint document library not list as you have mentioned folder under list. So in order to get all your documents inventory from SharePoint library, please download the below PowerShell script which give the csv output for all your files and folders.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-detail-report-of-all-b29ea8e2